# Force Apache to update log files path without restart in WAMP

Tags: apache, logging, wamp, httpd.conf

How can I **force Apache** (part of **WAMP**) to **write** the **new logs** in the **new log files** without restarting the server?

---

In **Apache2\conf\httpd.conf** I updated the path for `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` directives.

- before:

  ```
  ErrorLog ../logs/a.log
  ...
  CustomLog ../logs/b.log common
  ```
- after:

  ```
  ErrorLog ../logs/a2.log
  ...
  CustomLog ../logs/b2.log common
  ```

The `LogLevel` and `LogFormat` directives were not changed.

After I changed them, I managed (I don't know how - accidentally or it was done automatically, but I am sure that I didn't restart the server explicitly) to get the new logs in the new files. Maybe this didn't happen immediately, because I observed this after 20 minutes (the new log files were created and the new logs went to them, not to the old ones). This is what I wanted to achieve!

But then I changed the paths again:

- `../logs/a2.log` => `../logs/a3.log`
- `../logs/b2.log` => `../logs/b3.log`

but the logs didn't go to the new path (they were still written to `../logs/a2.log` and `../logs/b2.log`).

I was thinking at the following 2 **possible approaches** that could solve my problem, but probably there is another approach:

1. Reload the whole **httpd.conf** without stopping the Apache (or any other component from WAMP).
2. Force only the **`ErrorLog`** and **`CustomLog`** lines to be updated (in terms of executing some commands directly in cmd, ignoring the httpd.conf file).

---

**Details**:

- WAMP5 1.6.6 (*upgrading is not a solution*)

  - Apache 2.0.59 (*released about 9 years ago*)
- I cannot restart the server because the users need to access the applications without interruptions.

Comment: I don't use wamp, but in general `apachectl graceful` can be used to reload the config without killing existing connections.

Comment: or apache reload (httpd reload)

Comment: Aren't these solutions for Linux?

Comment: Do you mean something like logrotate?

Comment: The purpose at this moment is just to change the location for the output. Then, I can use `CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe ../logs/b.%Y.%m.%d-%H.log 3600" common` . So, now I just want to use the new log files until the first Apache service restart.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, `apache.exe -k restart` is mildly graceful -- in-flight requests have 30 seconds to complete.

Beyond this, you're probably out of luck for a safe way to rename files being written to on Windows. You should never be running a single HTTP server for this very reason. You have no way to do any routine maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question correctly you need to tell me which logging api is being used in your apache configuration.

If using log4j then see the following URL [Log4j Automatic Configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticReconfiguration)

You will find information here which talks about setting the monitorInterval property, in the Log4j configuration file. Setting this attribute to a non-zero value ( > 5) will result in the file being checked the next time a log event is evaluated and/or logged and the monitorInterval, specified in seconds, has elapsed since the last check

Comment: The question is related to the server logging system, not to the logging per application. In WAMP, Apache uses a module for logging `mod_log_config.so` which is loaded in **httpd.conf**.